# Gatsby Cloud doesn't seem to be using firebase.json file when deploying Gatsby site to Firebase CDN

Tags: firebase, gatsby

I have a somewhat involved deployment process for my Gatsby site which is hosted on Firebase, so I'm using [Gatsby Cloud](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/cloud/) to build the site and deploy it to Firebase. I have a set of cache-control rules that I want the site to use when I deploy to Firebase which are found in the firebase.json file (shown below). It works fine when I deploy the site from my local machine, but when Gatsby Cloud builds and deploys to firebase, it seems to ignore the firebase.json file in favor of some other configuration which I can't see, so the cache-control rules get ignored. Any idea how I can get Gatsby Cloud to honor my firebase.json file?

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "static/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(css|js)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "sw.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "page-data/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "cache-control",
            "value": "cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. You need to copy the firebase.json file over into the public/ folder. Quick hack would be to just copy it, better would be to use the onPostBuild hook

Something like this:

```
exports.onPostBuild = () => {
  fs.copySync(
    path.join(__dirname, '/firebase.json'),
    path.join(__dirname, '/public/firebase.json')
  )
}
```